# Share specific section of page on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have multiple facebook share links on my page, corresponding to each section of the page.  Is it possible to provide facebook a unique description for each of these shares?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook retrieves the URL being shared and looks for the [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/checklist/#opengraphtags) meta tags for the description. Therefore a specific URL can only have a single description. You would have to create different URLs which returned different OG tags in order to achieve this (although the URLs could return the same content). For example, you could add a `section` query parameter which causes the server to return different OG descriptions. Each Share widget would set the appropriate query parameter for that section.