# Share image including some attributes (e.g. description) on Facebook over web without app validation hassle

Tags: facebook, image, share, facebook-sharer

I want to share an image from a website on Facebook and pass some attributes (e.g. a description) to the status update, all done by clicking on a link.

A few months ago this worked fine using the sharer.php but by now this script just accepts a URL as parameter and scrapes the target site for Open Graph meta tags. This new approach isn't very helpfull if you just want to share elements on a page instead of the whole page.

Yeah, I could create an app and use the feed dialog to achieve my goal. But I honestly don't want to walk through the tedious app validation process just to share an image with some additional info!

So, does anyone know of a way to avoid this app hassle? Perhaps some undocumented parameters for the new implementation of the sharer.php?

Comment: Are you actually talking about the status message, or just the attributes of the shared link (title, description, etc)? And no, the new Share button/dialog accepts the just URL as its only parameter, and everything else is fetched from the OG meta tags on the URL that is shared. And as for the _“tedious app validation process”_ – you are aware that submitting an app for approval is only necessary if you want to use Open Graph actions or have it show up in the app center, right? Just to create an app to have an app id to use with the feed dialog, you don’t need that …

Comment: Thanks for your input, @CBroe! I tried to fix my ambiguous wording. And no, I'm not aware of the possibility to use an app ID without creating an app. Gonna check that out.

Comment: I did not say without _creating_ an app, I said without submitting it for approval.

Comment: It isn't possible to prefill the comment with sharer.php, and the other information must come from OG tags. You have to [use different URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22186466/1284662) to share different things.

Comment: Doh! I found the error. Forgot to set an e-mail in the app settings, thought I have to put that info into the app details! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, @CBroe!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for app validation - as @CBroe correctly stated! So the feed dialog IS an adequate solution!

Background: I assumed an app needs validation to go live. But I just didn't set up my app properly to make it available to every Facebook user.

See the comments to gloat over my stupidity. ;)